# Call method only once on segment controller's segment selection

Tags: ios

I have a segment controller.on segment click an API is called.i don't want to call it again and again on each click of segment.so i want it to be called like for first(name) segment only if first(name) segment is not selected already. 
if same segment is selected multiple times api should not be called again.

Please Help!!
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

create an instance variable like `NSInteger currentIndex;` and initiate it with your default(first)segment value, and then do as follows

```
-(IBAction)segmentControlClicked:(UISegmentedControl*)sender
{
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex != currentIndex)
    {
        // your api call
        currentIndex = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;
    }
}
```